# Add remotely WordPress Posts to my blog, but how to add picture?

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, xml-rpc

I have this blog post on my blog:

http://lifepearls.herobo.com/2011/06/tom-hardy-is-bane/

I make posts from my php code with this:

```
function wpPostXMLRPC($title,$body,$rpcurl,$username,$password,$category,$keywords='',$encoding='UTF-8') {
    $title = htmlentities($title,ENT_NOQUOTES,$encoding);
    $keywords = htmlentities($keywords,ENT_NOQUOTES,$encoding);

    $content = array(
        'title'=>$title,
        'description'=>$body,
        'mt_allow_comments'=>0,  // 1 to allow comments
        'mt_allow_pings'=>0,  // 1 to allow trackbacks
        'post_type'=>'post',
        'mt_keywords'=>$keywords,
        'categories'=>array($category)
    );
    $params = array(0,$username,$password,$content,true);
    $request = xmlrpc_encode_request('metaWeblog.newPost',$params);
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $rpcurl);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 1);
    $results = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $results;

}
```

However, I dont know how to add the image, and what field.

Here is the image from the dashboard for the image:

http://lifepearls.herobo.com/path.jpg

This is the manual way to add my image to the post, since it is a
part of the specific template.

How do I add my image remotely, any idea?

Comment: if you have FTP access to the site, you could upload the image, then make use of this plugin to automatically create the media item. http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/auto-post-images-api/. in fact, you could probably look at the shortcode action to see how that plugin works for a better idea

Answer (score 1):

We've created a plugin ( [WP Remote Connections](http://codecanyon.net/item/wp-remote-connections/9491513) ) that can send posts, pages, and media from one WordPress installation to one or many other WordPress :) It might be what you are looking for.

Comment: hello https://prnt.sc/10sdbrb  i  am getting same error

Answer (score 0):

The [MetaWebLog API](http://www.xmlrpc.com/metaWeblogApi) has no ways to transmit images or other resources. You're lost, except you transfer the images via ftp/sftp and just `<img>`-include them.